# Links in xslt work in IE but not Firefox and Chrome, why?

Tags: xslt, hyperlink

I have recently started web programming and I have inherited the following issue and unfortunately am the only web programmer here now, so I have no one I can go to for help. In the xslt code below, there are two links that work in IE but not in Firefox nor Chrome: $("#roatitle").click(function() and $("#incometitle").click(function(). These use chartroaroe and chartnetincome. The data displays correctly and the headers are correct (ROA/ROE, Net Income); the cursor changes to a pointer when hovering but clicking does nothing. I have tried to cut the code down as much as possible for this forum and hopefully did not remove something important; so, how do I get this to work in Firefox and Chrome?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/chartsdatareport">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Company Tearsheet</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var roeValues = [];
        var roaValues = [];

        <xsl:apply-templates select="privateroaroeratiosdata"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="privateincomeratiosdata"/>

        var chartroaroe;
        var chartnetincome;

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">        
<![CDATA[        
        function formatRating(val)  {
          if (val == 0 && ratingTA == 0 && entitytype=='Holding Company'){
                   return '<span style="font-size:20px">N/A</span>';
            } else {
                   return '<span style="color:white">'+val+'</span>';
            }
        }
]]>    
</xsl:text>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
              chartrating = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                    renderTo: 'rating',
                    type: 'column',
                    backgroundColor: '#666666',
                    margin: 0,
                    spacingBottom: 5,
                    spacingLeft: 0,
                    spacingRight: 0
                 },
                 credits: {
                   enabled: false
                 },
                 exporting: {
                   buttons: {
                     exportButton: {
                       enabled: false
                     },
                     printButton: {
                       enabled: false
                     }
                   }
                 },
                 title: {
                   text: 'Banking Insight Rating',
                    style: {
                      display: 'none'
                    }
                 },
                 xAxis: {
                    categories: rating,
                   gridLineWidth: 0,
                   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                   lineColor: 'transparent',
                   lineWidth: 0,
                   tickLength: 0,
                   minorTickLength: 0,
                   labels: {
                     enabled: true,
                     style: {
                       font: 'bold 26px Verdana',
                       color: '#FFFFFF'
                     },
                     y: -35,
                     formatter: function(){
                       return formatRating(this.value);
                     }
                   }
                 },
                 yAxis: {
                   gridLineWidth: 0,
                   lineWidth: 0,
                   min: 0,
                   max: 100,
                   labels: {
                     enabled: false
                   },
                   title: {
                     text: '',
                     margin: 0
                   }
                 },
                 plotOptions: {
                   column: {
                     stacking: 'normal',
                     borderWidth: 0,
                     point: {
                       events: {
                         mouseOut: function(){
                           $("#ratingtooltip").hide();
                         },
                         mouseOver: function(){
                           $("#ratingtooltip").show();
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   },
                   series: {
                     pointWidth: 50
                   }
                 },
                 tooltip: {
                   enabled: false
                 },
                 legend:{
                   enabled: false
                 },
                 series: [{
                   color: '#005A84',
                    data: revertrating
                 },{
                   color: '#FF9100',
                    data: rating
                 }]
              });

              chartroaroe = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                    renderTo: 'roaroe',
                    type: 'line'
                 },
                 credits: {
                   enabled: false
                 },
                 exporting: {
                   buttons: {
                     exportButton: {
                       enabled: false
                     },
                     printButton: {
                       enabled: false
                     }
                   }
                 },
                 title: {
                    text: '<span id="roatitle">ROA/ROE</span>',
                    style: {
                      fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: '#666666',
                      cursor: 'pointer'
                    }
                 },
                 plotOptions: {
                   line: {
                     marker: {
                       symbol: 'circle'
                     }
                   },
                   series: {
                     dataLabels: {
                       enabled: true
                     }
                   }
                 },
                 tooltip: {
                   animation: false,
                   pointFormat: '<span style="color:#666666">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                   style: {
                     fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                     color: '#666666'
                   }
                 },
                 legend: {
                   itemStyle: {
                     fontSize: '12px',
                     fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                     color: '#666666'
                   }
                 },
                 xAxis: {
                    categories: roaroequarters.reverse(),
                    labels: {
                      style: {
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana'
                      }
                    }
                 },
                 yAxis: {
                    title: {
                       text: ''
                    }
                 },
                 series: [{
                    name: 'Return on Avg Equity (ROE) (Mixed)',
                    color: '#005A84',
                    data: roeValues.reverse()
                 },{
                    name: 'Return on Avg Assets (ROA) (Mixed)',
                    color: '#FF9100',
                    data: roaValues.reverse()
                 }]
              });

              chartnetincome = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                    renderTo: 'netincome',
                    type: 'line'
                 },
                 credits: {
                   enabled: false
                 },
                 exporting: {
                   buttons: {
                     exportButton: {
                       enabled: false
                     },
                     printButton: {
                       enabled: false
                     }
                   }
                 },
                 title: {
                    text: '<span id="incometitle">Net Income</span>',
                    style: {
                      fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: '#666666',
                      cursor: 'pointer'
                    }
                 },
                 plotOptions: {
                   line: {
                     marker: {
                       symbol: 'circle'
                     }
                   },
                   series: {
                     dataLabels: {
                       enabled: true,
                       formatter: function(){
                         return addCommas(this.y);
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 },
                 tooltip: {
                   animation: false,
                   pointFormat: '<span style="color:#666666">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
                   style: {
                     fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                     color: '#666666'
                   }
                 },
                 legend: {
                   itemStyle: {
                     fontSize: '12px',
                     fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                     color: '#666666'
                   }
                 },
                 xAxis: {
                    categories: incomequarters.reverse(),
                    labels: {
                      style: {
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana'
                      }
                    }
                 },
                 yAxis: {
                    title: {
                       text: ''
                    }
                 },
                 series: [{
                    name: 'Net Income',
                    color: '#005A84',
                    data: netIncomeValues.reverse()
                 },{
                    name: 'Net Interest Income',
                    color: '#FF9100',
                    data: netInterestIncomeValues.reverse()
                 }]
              });

            $("#roatitle").click(function()
             {
               <xsl:text>parent.getHighlineTop().newTab('/bats/company/PopupReport.do?entityID=</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="//companyheader/id"/>
               <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&report=DYRPT%3A%3A118]]></xsl:text>               
               <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="$link_value"/>
               <xsl:text>',null,true,'companytabicon');</xsl:text>
             });

            $("#incometitle").click(function()
             {
               <xsl:text>parent.getHighlineTop().newTab('/bats/company/PopupReport.do?entityID=</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="//companyheader/id"/>
               <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&report=EXCEL%3A%3A621]]></xsl:text>               
               <xsl:text>','</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="$link_value"/>
               <xsl:text>',null,true,'companytabicon');</xsl:text>
             });

          });
               </script>
                   #netincome, #roaroe {
                       width: 49%;
                       height: 250px;
                       float:left;
                   }
              </style>
         </head>
         <body>
      <script src="/bats/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="/bats/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
      <script src="/bats/js/uiUtilBats.js"></script>
           <div id="netincome"></div>
           <div id="roaroe"></div>
           <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="fintable">
           </table>
         </body>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="escapos">\'</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="link_value">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="//companyheader/title"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$apos"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$escapos"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="privateroaroeratiosdata">
    <xsl:for-each select="./datapoint">
      roeValues.push(<xsl:value-of select="./roevalue"/>);
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="privateincomeratiosdata">
    <xsl:for-each select="./datapoint">
      netIncomeValues.push(<xsl:value-of select="./netincome"/>);
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
            select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It is difficult to debug by reading lots of lines of code, consider to post a link to the page so that we can check with the browser. And of course make sure you have checked yourself whether the error console in Firefox or Chrome does not tell you anything about the cause of the problem.

Comment: OK, I cut out more of the code; hopefully I didn't take out too much. I see no errors from either Firefox or Chrome, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a URL we can visit? Does the Javascript code and the charts API you use work with Firefox and Chrome in a static HTML document so that we at least know the problem is related to trying to use it in a result of an XSLT transformation?

Comment: unfortunately, as it is a part of our paid product, there is no direct URL available I can give you. Everything works beautifully, the charts generated, the data displayed, all other links, etc, except for these two links. As I only have this as an XSLT code, I dont know if it is ok in a static HTML doc. When I look at it via Inspect Element in firefox, the code looks ok, and the code for the link $("#roatitle").click(function() has been transformed and looks correct. I can see no errors.

Comment: Could you provide the resulting HTML snippet generated by this XSLT?